# How to set the type of a window event?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to declare the type for an event in a function in a react component like this but typescript complains `Cannot find namespace Window` and it makes no difference if I lowercase `window`

```
handleChange = (event: Window.Event) => {
        console.log("event");

  }
```

The Window interface in TypeScript has these (and other properties)

```
interface Window extends EventTarget, WindowTimers, WindowSessionStorage, WindowLocalStorage, WindowConsole, GlobalEventHandlers, IDBEnvironment, WindowBase64 {
    animationStartTime: number;
    applicationCache: ApplicationCache;
    clientInformation: Navigator;
    closed: boolean;
    crypto: Crypto;
    defaultStatus: string;
    devicePixelRatio: number;
    doNotTrack: string;
    document: Document;
    event: Event;
```

How do I set the type of that event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type you're looking for is just called `Event`. `window.event` is a member of the `window` object that has the type of `Event`; it's not the type itself, hence why you're getting an error when you try to use it as one.

Comment: Four years later and this answer is still helpful. I was getting confused as to why `MouseEvent` wasn't working, but get it now. Thanks!

Comment: Kool, doesn't know you can just directly use it `Event`, and also find out there're others, such as `DragEvent` etc.